# Adaptive payments (preapprovals and chained) pages don't display correctly anymore

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

Since yesterday paypal adaptive payments pages seem to display malformed, part of the page is hidden or stretched, some confirmation button is missing. Looking to the console when landing on the preapproval page, for example, we see a lot of 404 errors related to css and javascripts that should be loaded opening the page but the page can't find. We're experiencing this frustrating issue in Italy and we've just opened a MTS ticket on paypal. Any idea for workaround? It's totally blocking for us and for all our customers.

[image: console errors on the paypal preapproval page]

Comment: Based on several tests we've performed and on the different behaviour we have on the page trying to connect with the main national carrier or through 4g mobile carrier it might be a network problem. But we're still in contact with the MTS support at paypal to have a secure answere and hopefully a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved on sept 6th, it was a css issue and the fix is internally referenced in the ticket number: 180904-000230 and 180817-000081. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.